# break statement in Java

Tags: java, methods, break

I wrote a 'setX' method in Java that says that if x value ( (x,y) ) is negative, the value of x wont be change, and the main() will continue as usual.

```
void setX (int num)
{
       if (num < 0)
            break;
       else
       {
            _x = num; 
       }
}
```

Am I right ?
I am not sure because of the break issue, is the break statement just break from the current method ?

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant

```
public void setX(int x) {
   if (x >= 0)
        _x = x; 
}
```

Comment: + 1, although I prefer `public void setX(int _x) {
   if (_x >= 0)
        this._x = _x; 
}`, but I'm not really liking the fact that he's using an underscore in a variable name like that..

Answer (score 10):

`break` is used only in loops (while, for).

If you want to exit the method, use `return` instead.

Comment: but the method returns nothing... it's a void

Answer (score 0):

you should use `return`. `break` is to break loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return;` here.  `break` is used to break out of loops.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java tutorial, [break](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) is for use with `switch`, `for`, `while`, and `do`-`while` loops.  It doesn't go in if statements.  For a `switch` the `break` keeps the `switch` from falling through to the next `case`, which it would otherwise do.  For loops it stops looping regardless of the loop guards.

A `break` statement can either be unlabeled, in which case it goes to where control would normally resume after the `switch` or loop, or labeled, in which case it goes to the label (almost as if it were a `goto` with strict constraints on where it can come from).

To get out of the current method, use `return`.  A return with no value is the proper statement to leave a `void` method.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work, but the break really isn't doing anything anyway.  why not just if(num>=0) _x = num;

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention might be a bit clearer if your logic was reversed;

```
void setX (int num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        _x = num;
}
```